# Single variable for multiple named placeholder

Tags: php, pdo

Hello so I've been thinking of using a single variable for multiple named placeholder. My current code is here:

```
$checkSponsor = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tables WHERE l1_1 = :sponsorID OR l1_2 = :sponsorID OR l1_3 = :sponsorID OR l1_4 = :sponsorID OR l1_5 = :sponsorID");
$checkSponsor->execute(array('sponsorID' => $sponsorid));
$row = $checkSponsor->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    if($row > 0) {
        foreach ($checkSponsor as $s) {
            echo $s['l1_1']."<br />";
            echo $s['l1_2']."<br />";
            echo $s['l1_3']."<br />";
            echo $s['l1_4']."<br />";
            echo $s['l1_5']."<br />";
        }
    }
```

I tried this code and nothing is echo'ed out. Just blank white page.

Since I am using the same placeholder, can I just execute the array with one variable only?

Comment: 1) **Try it!** 2) You use the method `prepare`, so look it up in the manual and read the manual page.

Comment: Alternatively slash it down to `:var IN (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)`.

Comment: @mario, should it be (c1, c2, c3) or ('c1', 'c2', 'c3) ?

Comment: Ok @mario. Tried and still no luck

Comment: @FewFlyBy Update your question show your progress and where you are now

Comment: Did you get `PHP Warning: No luck - in example code on line 53`?

Comment: @mario I think that will throw a `FATAL ERROR` and not a warning :] (^ Have to remember that one)

Comment: @mario I updated my post, sorry

Comment: @Rizier123 I updated my post, sorry